# Difference between in der Suche nach, bei der Suche nach and auf der Suche nach

Tags: preposition

I know the expressions "in der Suche nach" "bei der Suche nach" and "auf der Suche nach" which all mean "in the search for" but with different prepositions and I don't know when to use each of them I searched in Reverso Context and it showed that "bei der Suche nach" means "During the search for/of" and "in der Suche nach" means in search for something (but in a quest or something like a serious mission) and "auf der Suche nach" means in searching for (a normal search like a job) please explain simply the difference between the three

My question is simply what is the difference between:
In der Suche nach
Auf der Suche nach
Bei der Suche nach
And please tell me if the information I said above is correct or not

Comment: "auf" and "bei" are both completely opaque in meaning and sound interchangeable to me.

Answer (score 2):

- *auf der Suche sein nach* (= *suchen nach*) ⇒ to be searching for

> Ich bin auf der Suche nach einer Wohnung.
>
>  (I am searching for an apartment.)

- *bei der Suche nach* ⇒ while searching for

> Bei der Suche nach Metall bin ich auf einen Ring gestoßen.
>
>  (While searching for metal, I happened to find a ring.)

- *in der Suche*: This sounds less idiomatic to me and works only in particular expressions, for example:

> Ich stecke in der Suche nach neueren Informationen fest.
>
>  (I am stuck in the search for more recent information.)
>
> Welcher Begriff steht in der Suche?
> (= Welcher Begriff steht im Suchfeld?)
>
>  (Which term is in the search field?)

Comment: Yes thank you now I understand but I think "in der Suche nach" is used less commonly than the other two maybe you can use it like "Im Suchfeld" or in a quest of a search or something maybe but it is still correct but not common